# How to share declaration of integer between two forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently making some basic incremental game in c# in WFA. Here's the code:

```
namespace Xadrs
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public void Ref()
    {
        label2.Text = Points.ToString();
        button2.Text = "Level up! (" + Upgradeprice.ToString() + ")";
        label4.Text = Upgrade.ToString();
        label6.Text = Upgradeautoclick.ToString();
        button4.Text = "Level up PPS! (" + Upgradeautoclickprice.ToString() + ")";
    }
    public int ach_beginner = 0;
    public int ach_intermediate = 0;
    public int ach_expert = 0;
    public int ach_master = 0;



    int Points = 0; 
    int Upgrade = 1;
    int Upgradeautoclick = 0 ;
    int Upgradeautoclickprice = 110;
    int Upgradeprice = 25;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Ref();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Upgrade == 5)
        {
            Points++;
            Ref();
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Points += Upgrade;
        Ref();


    }



    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Points >= Upgradeprice)
        {
            Upgrade += 1;
            Points -= Upgradeprice;
            Upgradeprice += Upgradeprice / 4;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Nico points...");
        }
        Ref();

        if (Upgrade == 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Beginner: Reach 5 PPS.\nReward: AutoClick!", "ACHIEVEMENT UNLOCKED!");
            ach_beginner = 1;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            Upgradeautoclick = 1;
            button4.Visible = true;
            Ref();
        }
    }

    Form2 achievements = new Form2();

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show();            
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Points >= Upgradeautoclickprice)
        timer1.Interval = timer1.Interval / 2;
        Points -= Upgradeautoclickprice;
        Upgradeautoclickprice += Upgradeautoclickprice;
    }
```

and in form2 I want to have:

```
    if (ach_beginner = 1) 
    {
        //Text in this label = something like: Beginner - Reach 5 Points per click
        labelwithachievement.Visible = true;
    }
```

but the `ach_beginner` isn't declared in `form2`. I would like to somehow "connect" this integer to have its declaration from `form1` in `form2`.

Comment: What do you mean with "share declaration"?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a Parameter. You call the `Form2.Show` Method. As any other Method a method of Form2 can become a parameter. So in Form2 you could do the following:

```
public void Show(int ach_beginner)
{       
   //Do sth. with your int

   this.Show();
}
```

If you call Form2 on Form1 now you can pass your integer:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2.Show(ach_beginner);            
}
```

I think this is the easiest approach. Instead of overriding the Show Method you could make a Property as well. In Form2 declare:

```
public int AchBeginner {get;set;}
```

In Form1 you set this value before you call the Show Method:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2.AchBeginner = ach_beginner;
   Form2.Show();            
}
```

As David explained in comments, the value won't be updated on Form2. If you want to achieve this you could use an Interface:

```
public interface IBeginner
{
   int AchBeginner{get;set;}
}

public void Form1 : Form, IBeginner
{
   public int AchBeginner{get;set;}

   //The place you create Form2
   Form2.Beginner = this;
}

public void Form2 : Form
{
   public IBeginner Beginner{get;set;}

   //Here you can access
   int achBeginner = Beginner.AchBeginner:
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment from the question author i think an event would be the most usefull think. So you can tell your Form2 that your character on Form1 reaches level 5. For example:

```
public class LevelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   public int Level {get;}

   public LevelEventArgs(int level)
   {
      Level = level;
   }
}

//Form1 need to implement an Event which later can notify any subscriber (Form2 in this case)
public class Form1 : Form
{
   public event EventHandler<LevelEventArgs> LevelUp;

   //When your character reach new level do following:
   LevelUp?.Invoke(this, new LevelEventArgs(ach_beginner));

   //Show Form2
   Form2 form = new Form2(this);
   form.Show();
}
```

Form2 needs to subscribe this event now. For this you need to put Form1 to Form2 (or better an Interface as described above)

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
   public Form2(Form form1)
   {
       //Register Event LevelUp from Form1
       form1.LevelUp += (args) => 
       {
          if (args.Level == 5)
          //Level 5 reached
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This passes by value.  If the value changes on `Form1`, it won't be updated on the instance of `Form2`.

Comment: @David And why is that a problem in this context?

Comment: @Servy: I don't know, since I don't fully know how this application is used, but it could be a problem and is certainly worth noting.

Comment: @David he tells nothing from updating this value. So i guess this works. You are right if the value should becomes updates he will need ref or events.

Comment: @David When you start my project, you have level (int) 1, and empty achievement window (Form2). In this case, ach_beginner = 0. When you reach the 5th level, the ach_beginner in form1 changes value to 1. And in this moment, i need to change the visibility of label in form2. This is what i mean.

Comment: @Quickshot135: If this update needs to happen automatically then you may need to look into exposing and subscribing to events as well, not just passing around the values.  (Or perhaps switch to something like WPF, where 2-way model binding updates everything connected to the backing data automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it as sharing the integer itself, instead think of it as `Form2` has a dependency on something in `Form1`.

Since the variable is currently *public* (we'll get to that in a minute), at the simplest all you need to do is provide `Form2` with a reference to the instance of `Form1`.  Put a property on `Form2` and require a value in its constructor:

```
private Form1 form1Instance;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1Instance = form1;
}
```

Then when you create an instance of `Form2`, pass it a reference to the current instance of `Form1`:

```
Form2 achievements = new Form2(this);
```

Then in `Form2` you can refer to its new member variable to get information from `Form1`:

```
if (this.form1Instance.ach_beginner == 1)
```

---

Note regarding public variables...  It's generally considered best practice to expose *properties* publicly instead of *variables*.  So replace this:

```
public int ach_beginner = 0;
```

with this:

```
public int Ach_Beginner { get; set; }
```

And update references to it accordingly.  There are a variety of reasons for this, but ultimately the idea is that a class should hide its values and provide access to them rather than just provide the values themselves.

---

This is a pretty simple start to the idea of providing a dependency to an object, and there are a number of places you can go from here.  For example, if you don't want to pass around entire forms as dependencies (since they include considerably more data/functionality than is otherwise needed for the dependency), you can encapsulate your values in an object of their own and pass around *that* object as the dependency.

Extrapolating from there, you can continue to separate business logic from UI elements (like forms and controls), and begin to move your logic into those business logic objects and components.  This will make your logic more portable onto other UI platforms, easier to test, etc.

For example, suppose you have a class such as:

```
public class LevelInfo // guessing on an appropriate name here
{
    public int Ach_Beginner { get; set; }
    public int Ach_Intermediate { get; set; }
    public int Ach_Expert { get; set; }
    public int Ach_Master { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `Form1` you use that object instead:

```
private LevelInfo levelInfo = new LevelInfo();

// elsewhere...

levelInfo.Ach_Beginner = 1;
// etc.
```

Then `Form2` can require a reference to *that* object:

```
private LevelInfo levelInfo;

public Form2(LevelInfo level)
{
    this.levelInfo = level;
}
```

and use that object:

```
if (this.levelInfo.Ach_Beginner == 1)
```

At this point `LevelInfo` is de-coupled from the UI and can contain portable business logic/information.

Comment: Your solution is contrary to your own explanation.  You've stated that there's a dependency on this *one value*, and yet you've exposed an entire form, full of all sorts of behavior that there is no dependency on at all.

Comment: So given that you realize the solution you presented is not in fact a good solution, why present it?  Why not suggest a *good* solution instead?

Comment: I think in this case an Interface would be the best solution.